# How to set smp_affinity of irqs when irqbalance service is enabled

Tags: linux-kernel

I have set smp_affinity for irqs, but when irqbalance service is enabled, the smp_affinity was modified.
How to keep the smp_affinity same when irqbalance service is enabled?

I have tried to set banirq of irqbalance, it works. But when irqbalance service restarts, the smp_affinity will still be modified. Is there any other useful ways?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.